# MVC5 DataAnnotation [NotequalTo] could not be found assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, system.web

I am doing an MVC5, Framework 4.5.1 App. I have a Entity with DataAnnotation. I need to compare that two properties are different.. `OldPassword` and `NewPassowrd`.

I think the best wat to compare it, is using `[NotEqualTo]`  Validation. But have an error `The type or namespace do not exists. Are you missing an assembly?`.
I have a reference to `System.Web.Mvc`

What I a missing?

Comment: Did you add "using Foolproof;"  statement to the class?

Comment: And here is the link to the Foolproof nuget: https://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Comment: There's no [NotEqualTo] attribute in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.